# Is there a function for inlining an asset (eg css) in Laravel?

Tags: css, laravel, performance, inline, assets

I have a fairly small stylesheet which is currently imported using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ inline('/css/app.css') }}">
```

I'd like to investigate the potential performance benefits of inlining it (ie into a `<style>` element).

I had assumed that there might be something like an `inline` blade function - and [found reference to one](https://jigsaw.tighten.co/docs/compiling-assets/#inlining-your-assets), but I think it's part of Jigsaw build (for static sites) and it certainly doesn't exist now in Laravel 8.

I understand I could write something to pull in the file - but with so many utility function in Laravel, I had assumed there'd be something already.

Comment: I found this library which could help you (https://github.com/fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner)

Comment: Thanks, but that does something different - it inlines the css from a `style` tag into `style` attributes - not from a separate file into a `style` tag

Comment: Just find an idea, why not use a custom blade tag which will get css file content and return it in inline style ? I shouldn't be so difficult (sorry, don't know your Laravel level :-) )

Comment: As I've said, I know I could do that but with so many utility functions already built in Laravel, I'm asking if there's something already there.

Comment: Never see something directly built into Laravel.

Comment: If all you want is to copy/paste the contents of the file, php's [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) does what you want. `<style>{!! file_get_contents(asset('css/sheet.css') !!}</style>`. I don't think you're gonna get performance out of doing that though.

Comment: I agree with IGP, but you may want to pull the file internally rather than using `asset()` which will perform an HTTP request, like `<style>{!! file_get_contents(public_path('css/sheet.css')) !!}</style>`.

Comment: I could have worded this better: "...which will [return a URL causing `file_get_contents()` to] perform an HTTP request..."